# How do I want to expand the table? Angular14

Tags: angular, html-table

this is my table

I want in `th` `over 1 year`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wnesxu?file=src/app/pur/com1/com1.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this?

```
<th style="overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;">
    Over 1 Year
</th>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7eupgi)